# Ubuntu OS Desktop Screen Zoomed In Too Far

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, zoom

I'm running Ubuntu Linux on a Virtual Machine using VMWare Player. When I first installed Ubuntu everything was smaller than I prefered and was hard to read so I messed around with a lot of settings to make things bigger, I ended up taking it too far and everything became extremely big and I then got side tracked for a while. Now I have no idea what I did to change the settings and I can't find anywhere to change exactly the part I need to unzoom. Everything I've found online is to change the icon sizes, text size but not the file menus in the dialog GUIs and the overall OS desktop zoom. This picture should help to demonstrate the problem.

[image: Ubuntu Zoomed]

If you notice the slide bar on the far right, that's there because the actual desktop is so far zoomed in I have to scroll up and down side to side just to see everything on the OS screen (At first impression you may think the scrollbar is there because I don't have the virtual machine screen fully displayed but if you compare the far left Windows icon with the far right Windows time and date you will see that the Virtual Machine is in fact fully displayed). It's practically impossible to work on this setup now.

Comment: It's not zoomed in but the text size is set to big. There should be an option in the System Settings to change that if I remember correctly.

Comment: The Desktop Home Screen is zoomed in. That's why there is a scroll bar to the right and at the bottom.

Comment: I see. I thought you were referring to that big text.

Comment: Both are the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by going into **System Settings** -> **Universal Access** and turning **Large Text** off.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up saying, "The HELL with this!", and I installed a new image of Ubuntu onto my virtual machine. Lesson learned! Why did you get a minus one for this answer?